# red5 streaming video files vod

Tags: streaming, red5, mpeg, xuggler

I have a lot of very large recorded mpeg.ts files (each several hours) on a server and I want them to stream to a website.
I was thinking to use red5 with xuggler. 
My client could request a file, and red 5 could stream it to the client.
Xuggler could transcode the stream on the fly to flash video.

Is this a good way to go? 
Can anybody direct me to demo code?

Thank you

Comment: If you plan to provide .FLV files only why not convert them in advance using FFMPEG? Save yourself a lot of headache.